# Select a color onclick, then "paint" another div that color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, html

I'm trying to build a form that will allow users to specify colors of objects by first clicking on their preferred color, then the target object (in this case represented by DIVs). I can understand basic Javascript (and a little jQuery), but am lost as to how to approach this.

Here is a basic HTML page to illustrate basically what I'm trying to do. There are 3 colors to choose from - I'm guessing an onclick event should select one. Below these 3 colors are 4 target divs. After selecting a color and clicking a target div, its background color should change to the selected color and the hidden form value should change to the color number (0,1 or 2).

What is the simplest way of approaching this?

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div {background-color:#000000;width:25px;height:25px;margin:4px;float:left;}
h4 {clear:both;padding-top:10px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<script language="JavaScript">
var colors = ["#0000FF", "#999999", "#FF0000"];
</script>

<form name="myForm" action="form.html" method="get">

<h4>Select A Color:</h4>
<div style="background-color:#0000FF;" name="color0">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="background-color:#999999;" name="color1">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="background-color:#FF0000;" name="color2">&nbsp;</div>

<h4>Then click the squares to set them to the selected color(s):</h4>
<div name="square0">&nbsp;</div>
<div name="square1">&nbsp;</div>
<div name="square2">&nbsp;</div>
<div name="square3">&nbsp;</div>

<input type="hidden" name="square0" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="square1" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="square2" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="square3" value="">

<input type="submit" value="Save The Colors!">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: create a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Looks like a good setup.. I suggest that you attempt some javascript. Let us know what you tried and what went wrong.

Comment: As @showdev suggests. You need to use JavaScript and possibly jquery. No one is going to just do this for you as it's too broad and you haven't made any attempt. Have a go, if you get stuck on specific aspects, ask questions about them aspects.

Comment: I agree that you should try javascript. Just set up some functions, one that fires on clicking a color and sets the hidden input, and another that fires on clicking a div, and sets it's color to a form input. It should be brief and easy. However, I disagree about jQuery. It is certainly not necessary for this and would probably be complicating it more than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use names on divs.  Use id's or classes.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div#colorSelection div{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
div#squareContainer div{
    border:1px solid black;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
div.selectedColor{
    border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script language="JavaScript">
var colors = ["#0000FF", "#999999", "#FF0000"];
</script>

<form name="myForm" action="form.html" method="get">

<h4>Select A Color:</h4>
<div id="colorSelection">
    <div style="background-color:#0000FF;" id="color0">&nbsp;</div>
    <div style="background-color:#999999;" id="color1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div style="background-color:#FF0000;" id="color2">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<h4>Then click the squares to set them to the selected color(s):</h4>
<div id="squareContainer">
    <div id="square0">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="square1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="square2">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="square3">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="square0" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="square1" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="square2" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="square3" value="">

<input type="submit" value="Save The Colors!">

</form>

<script>
$('div#colorSelection').on('click', 'div', function(event){
    $('div.selectedColor').removeClass('selectedColor');
    $(this).addClass('selectedColor');
})
$('div#squareContainer').on('click', 'div', function(event){
    var color = $('div.selectedColor').css('background-color');
    var squareId = $(this).id;

    $(this).css({"background-color":color});
    $('input[name="'+squareId+'"]').val(color);

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this : http://jsfiddle.net/3Swtz/

```
var color;

$(".selection").click(function () {
   color = $(this).css("background-color");
});

$(".selected").click(function(){
   $(this).css("background-color", color)
});
```

Comment: This looks perfect, thank you!
Now I just need to figure out how to get the hidden input values to change to match the selected color.

Comment: dont forget to vote up and mark as answer